# ADD failed while integrating docker with jenkins

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, integration, addition

ADD target/maven-dev.jar maven dev.jar
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat target/maven-dev.jar: file does not exist
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
integrating docker with Jenkins.
how to solve this?

Comment: It complains because `target/maven-dev.jar` doesn't exist on the host computer. It's hard for us to say why it isn't there without more information.

Comment: Can post your Jenkinsfile or pipeline script? It hard to pin down exact cause

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.